# Inline Conditional Negation

Tags: java, javascript, c++, c

Is there an inline way to conditionally negate a value or expression without having to use a conditional evaluation such as the following?:

```
result = (condition) ? value : -value;
result = value * ((condition) ? 1 : -1);
```

I'm currently working in JavaScript, but I've been wondering the same for other languages that use it.

Comment: What's wrong with what your doing now

Comment: No, that's pretty much how you do it

Comment: stack overflow isn't a good place for opinion-based questions.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: It just feels slightly redundant to write out "value : -value" or "1 : -1", but maybe that's just me :P I was thinking of somehow sticking a conditional negative sign to the front, but as far as I know, that's not possible

Comment: Do simply: `food = (monkey ? banana : cheese)`

Comment: This is a redundant question, leading to answers that do nothing but increase the number of wtfs/second (in other words, not useful).

Comment: `value * (2*(condition) - 1)`, in case you think that's somehow an improvement.

Comment: `for (result=value; condition; result*=-1) break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `(bool - !bool * 1) * value`. `(bool - !bool * 1)` returns `1` for true, `-1` for false. A method is probably overkill; stick to the original readable code. With C/C++ you can get away with a macro (but be careful `bool` will be evaluated twice).

**Edit: `(bool - !bool) * value` works in Javascript and PHP (haven't tested others).** I guess I added the `* 1` initially in case it couldn't figure out it was supposed to be an int :P

I'm not sure this is faster (though I believe arithmetic expressions are faster than branches), and as others have said, you probably don't need to worry about speed. You're not saving on many characters either :P

Comment: If you can get `(bool - !bool * 1) * value` to compile in Java/C# let me know.

Comment: It'll work in Javascript, which he's "currently working in", and it should work in C/C++ as tagged. C# isn't mentioned, and I'm not familiar with. Worst case, it'll be same as Java - you'll have a few casts, but I never said this was for readability :P

Comment: I was asking based on the tags. I don't really care tbh :P

Comment: haha well you raised my curiosity, and Java won't let you cast a boolean to a int xD so if you really want to you'd have to do `(bool ? 1 : 0)` which obfuscates the original task even further. C# isn't mentioned though xD

Comment: This was better than my suggestion, +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about readability, here's a somewhat easier to understand alternative:

```
result = value;
if(some_condition){
    result *= -1;
}
```